# Связанные списки jquery-chained, не обновляются зависимые

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую библиотеку jquery-chained
При клике пользователя все отрабатывается. Как обновить выбранные пункты с помощью слушателей ?

```
$("#mark option[value='" + mark_value + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
$("#series option[value='" + series_value + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Обновляется только select mark, series не обновляется.

```
<select id="mark" name="mark">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select id="series" name="series">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option value="series-3" data-chained="bmw">3 series</option>
    <option value="series-5" data-chained="bmw">5 series</option>
    <option value="series-6" data-chained="bmw">6 series</option>
    <option value="a3" data-chained="audi">A3</option>
    <option value="a4" data-chained="audi">A4</option>
    <option value="a5" data-chained="audi">A5</option>
</select>

$("#series").chained("#mark"); /* or $("#series").chainedTo("#mark");
```

Answer (score 0):

Использую такой код, теперь все хорошо, обновляется зависимый select и в нем можно выбрать необходимый пункт. Ест ли минусы у него, не знаю.

```
$('#mark').val(mark_value).trigger('change');
```

Comment: У него нет минусов.